# Problem sending string with Python to Arduino through serial port

Tags: python

I want to send string 50 to Arduino through serial port, the Arduino UNO seems it communicates with port COM25 but it doesnt receive the string properly:

```
import serial # if you have not already done so

ser = serial.Serial('COM25') 
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.write(b'50')  
ser.close()
```

Btw Arduino code is correct I checked it with other serial com programs. How can I fix the above code?

Comment: `serial.Serial()` resets Uno and it spends some time in bootloader after then. add a delay/sleep after serial.Serial

Comment: I dont understand ;so how can I send string in Python as done in hyperTerminal? My Ard code works with hyperTerminal but I have been looking for a day and couldn't find a code which work for Python.

Comment: you need to wait 2 seconds until sending something over that Serial from python. Serial Monitor resets the Arduino too when opening a connection. At opening of window, not before every sent data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AVR Arduinos (Uno, Nano, Mega) have auto-reset function. At opening of USB connection the circuit around USB resets the MCU. After reset the bootloader waits a second for a new upload. If the upload doesn't happen the bootloader starts the current sketch.

The `serial.Serial()` command in python opens the USB connection. With that the Arduino is reset and waits in bootloader while you send the data. The data doesn't arrive in your sketch. Add a two seconds wait time after Python's `serial.Serial()`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This was driving me nuts. Alternatively, I added a line in Arduino setup() to send a byte and waited for that in python to get things started.